# Uses deprecated APIs Error- Deprecated APIs will eventually be removed from the browser

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have woedpress site and in the PageSpeed Insights I am getting "`StorageType.persistent` is deprecated. Please use standardized `navigator.storage` instead." eroor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2g6j.png)

So can anyone help me on it to fix.

I want a solution of this error

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning not an error and can be found at your source code.

[image]

(from Google's Developer Tools)

Check for the file indicated in the warning and/or for any JS file you might have searching within it:

```
StorageType.persistent
```

If you've found it replace it to:

```
navigator. Storage
```

If you are using Cloudflare CDN they might be injecting a main.js ou invisible.js file probably causing the warning. Check first under 'Rules > Transform Rules > Managed Transforms' and disable Add Security header:

[image]

If that does not work even testing enabling the Developer mode on Cloudflare either you can ignore it since this is not an error or contact Cloudflare's support team.